# Plugin 'Device' not found (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am facing this error on remote debugging:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

ERROR: Plugin 'Statusbar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml
```

I'm getting these errors for all Plugins , when i run application on device and console panel give these. and how to debug javascript on xcode?? i don't have any idea about this.?

I'm Confused do due to these errors , if i'm hitting any methods of other plugins which also have same above error the method never get calls..

Comment: Have you actually installed the plugins that you are trying to use? Are you waiting for the `device.ready` event before calling the methods? Without seeing _any_ code it's very likely that you won't get a useful answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do the following step by step:

> 1) cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-device
>
> 2) cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar
>
> 3) cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
>
> 4) cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

Then try to re-run your ionic app.

That's only plugin specific issue will solved by removing and adding again.

Hope it will help.

Thank you

Comment: thanks it helped me

Comment: Glad to help you..